# somebody please explain about strings in c?

Tags: c, string

how to store two strings one after other without concatenation (we can increment the address)

```
char str[10];
scanf("%s",str);
str=str+9;
scanf("%s",str);
```

NOTE: Here if I give first string as BALA and 2nd as HI, it should print as HI after BALA . But HI should not replace BALA.

Comment: `str=str+9;` is error in your code because `str` is constant name

Answer (score 8):

You cannot increment (or change in any other way) an array like that, the array variable (`str`) is a constant which cannot be changed.

You can do it like so:

```
char str[64];

scanf("%s", str);
scanf("%s", str + strlen(str));
```

This will first scan into `str`, then immediately scan once more, starting the new string right on top of the terminating `'\0'` of the first string.

If you enter `"BALA"` first, the beginning of `str` will look like this:

```
     +---+---+---+---+----+
str: | B | A | L | A | \0 |
     +---+---+---+---+----+
```

and since `strlen("BALA")` is four, the next string will be scanned into the buffer starting right on top of the `'\0'` visible above. If you then enter `"HI"`, `str` will start like so:

```
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
str: | B | A | L | A | H | I | \0 |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

At this point, if you print `str` it will print as `"BALAHI"`.

Of course, this is *very dangerous and likely to introduce buffer overrun*, but that's what you wanted.

Comment: How to write the diagram by using text only like that?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want to do correctly perhaps you want to put the strings in an array.
So a modified version of your code would look something like

```
char strings[ARRAY_LENGTH][MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
char* str = strings[0];
scanf("%s",str);
str=strings[1];
scanf("%s",str);
```

Then to print all the strings you would have to loop over the array like this

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
{
    printf(strings[i]);
}
```

(you would have to define ARRAY_LENGTH and MAX_STRING_LENGTH)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking at some thing like this

```
    char arr[100] = {0,}, *str = NULL;
    /** initial String will be scanned from beginning **/
    str = arr;

    /** scan first string **/
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    /**  We need to replace NULL termination with space is space is delimiter  **/
    str += strlen(str)-1;
    *str = ' ' ;

     /** scan second string from address just after space, 
            we can not over ride the memory though **/

     fgets(str, 100 - strlen(str), stdin);

     printf("%s",arr);
```

Well incase you need the same with scanf

```
char arr[100] = {0,}, *str = NULL;
/** initial String will be scanned from beginning **/
str = arr;

/** scan first string **/
scanf("%s",str);

/**  We need to replace NULL termination with space is space is delimiter  **/
str += strlen(str);
*str = ' ' ;

/** scan second string from address just after space,
 *                 we can not over ride the memory though **/
str++;
scanf("%s",str);


printf("%s",arr);
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the restrictions of `scanf`'s `%s` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Moving in a similar direction to unwind, you can use the `%n` directive to determine how many bytes have been read. Don't forget to subtract any leading whitespace. You may also want to read [your manual regarding scanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) very carefully, but paying particular care to the "RETURN VALUE" section. Handling the return value is necessary to ensure a string was actually read and avoid undefined behaviour.

```
char str[64];
int whitespace_length, str_length, total_length;

/* NOTE: Don't handle errors with assert!
 *       You should replace this with proper error handling */
assert(scanf(" %n%s%n", &whitespace_length, str, &total_length) == 1);
str_length = total_length - str_length; 
assert(scanf(" %n%s%n", &whitespace_length, str + str_length, &total_length) == 1);
str_length += total_length - str_length;
```